# django-ouath-toolkit with social-auth

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-authentication

I'm trying to setup `social-auth` (`python-social-auth`) to talk to another Django project with `django-oauth-toolkit`.

I want Django project A to login using OAuth2 from Django project B. Django project A uses `social-auth` and project B uses `django-oauth-toolkit` as the OAuth2 provider.

Project A can successfully login to other OAuth2 providers such as Google, but I get the following error when trying to login using my custom made backend:

```
AuthStateMissing at /sso/complete/custom-backend/
Session value state missing.
```

This is how the custom backend has been implemented in Project A:

```
class CustomBackend(BaseOAuth2):
    name = 'custom-backend'
    EXTRA_DATA = [
        ('profile', 'org')
    ]

    def authorization_url(self):
        return "%s/oauth2/authorize" % self.setting("URL")

    def access_token_url(self):
        return "%s/oauth2/token" % self.setting("URL")

    def user_data(self, access_token, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = requests.get("%s/me/" % self.setting("URL"), headers={
            'Authorization': "Bearer %s" % access_token
        })
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception("Error while getting user details from auth source.")
        data = resp.json()

        return {
            'username': data['email'],
            'first_name': data['first_name'],
            'last_name': data['last_name'],
            'user_id': data['id'],
            'email': data['email']
        }
```

There is a setting called `SOCIAL_AUTH_CUSTOM_BACKEND_URL` which is equal to the base URL of project B (`http://localhost:8001` for testing).

The URL when Project B redirects to Project A (when the error is raised) is: `http://localhost:8000/sso/complete/custom-backend/?redirect_state=6kg4S1eitCMqTTzFGrm9uerG37UNkUPl&code=e64by72AkD2unMVVsGZCz0V2byuUyu&state=6kg4S1eitCMqTTzFGrm9uerG37UNkUPl`

Thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I discovered, HTTP cookies are *not* separated by ports on the same host. So I had project A (the OAuth2 client) running on `localhost:8000` and project B (the OAuth2 server) running on `localhost:8001`. Django's `sessionid` Cookie was getting overridden during the auth process, which caused this error.

The solution is to run the OAuth2 server on a different host (I just made an entry in `/private/etc/hosts` on macOS that looks like:

```
127.0.0.1    id.localhost
```

and updated `SOCIAL_AUTH_CUSTOM_BACKEND_URL` to `http://id.localhost:8001`.